# SageMaker Lifecycle configuration script - LR CF characters added when trying to copy into AWS on mac

Tags: amazon-web-services, special-characters, amazon-sagemaker

So I have a lifecycle configuration file that I want to use. I have used tools to make sure the illegal CR CF are stripped out and that it is unix friendly. However, there is no way to upload the file "as is" in AWS Sagemaker lifecycle configurations - you have to directly copy in the text, and that adds the CR LF characters back on my Mac. How do I get around this?

Comment: Line ending characters  are OS specific, so I think you need to use some tools as long as you write on mac. (As you may know, on windows, using notepat++ is recommended to modify. https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/issues/8 )

Comment: Yea, I have done it before on Windows but now I am on a mac and am trying to figure out which tool is easiest to use.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to upload via Sagemaker Notebook or EC2 instance and open file with binary viewer. If there is any illegal CF CR there, edit again and attach onto a Lifecycle either direct copy or aws cli command. That is what I did. (my error was not exactly this but some trailing character that is not supported by binary format). Hope you find the way!